# conflicted on when and when not to typecast in C?

Tags: c, casting

I was reading the GLibC reference on the searching and sorting functions
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Search_002fSort-Example.html) and in one of the code examples, typecasting is used while in the other, it is not:

First one:

```
int
compare_doubles (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const double *da = (const double *) a;
  const double *db = (const double *) b;

  return (*da > *db) - (*da < *db);
}
```

Second one:

```
int
critter_cmp (const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
  const struct critter *c1 = v1;
  const struct critter *c2 = v2;

  return strcmp (c1->name, c2->name);
}
```

Is there any reason why in the second example, something like

```
const struct critter *c1 = (const struct critter *)v1;
```

was not used? or was this done only for brevity?

Edit: Is casting in the first example necessary then if the compiler can deduce it? Are there any best practices for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conversion to or from `void *` and any object pointer type can safely be done without a cast.  This is specified in section 6.3.2.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type.  A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a
> pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
> to the original pointer.

Because of this, the second function is fine as is and the first function can safely be written as:

```
int
compare_doubles (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const double *da = a;
  const double *db = b;

  return (*da > *db) - (*da < *db);
}
```

As a general rule, you shouldn't cast unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @0___________ Good catch.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

None is required as `void *` can be converted to any pointer type.